# Pythonic way to create a dictionary by iterating

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write something that answers "what are the possible values in every column?"

I created a dictionary called `all_col_vals` and iterate from 1 to however many columns my dataframe has. However, when reading about this online, someone stated this looked too much like Java and the more pythonic way would be to use zip. I can't see how I could use zip here.

```py
all_col_vals = {}
for index in range(RCSRdf.shape[1]):
    all_col_vals[RCSRdf.iloc[:,index].name] = set(RCSRdf.iloc[:,index])
```

The output looks like `'CFN Network': {nan, 'N521', 'N536', 'N401', 'N612', 'N204'}, 'Exam': {'EXRC', 'MXRN', 'HXRT', 'MXRC'}` and shows all the possible values for that specific column. The key is the column name.

Comment: `{k: {*df[k]} for k in df}`?

Comment: If the above comment intimidates you, there's also the `unique` method: `{c: set(df[c].unique()) for c in df.columns}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think @piRSquared's comment is the best option, so I'm going to steal it as an answer and add some explanation.

## Answer

Assuming you don't have duplicate columns, use the following:

```
{k : {*df[k]} for k in df}
```

## Explanation

`k` represents a column name in `df`. You don't have to use the `.columns` attribute to access them because a `pandas.DataFrame` works similarly to a `python` `dict`

`df[k]` represents the series `k`

`{*df[k]}` unpacks the values from the series and places them in a set (`{}`) which only keeps distinct elements by definition ([see definition of a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics))).

Lastly, using list comprehension to create the `dict` is faster than defining an empty `dict` and adding new keys to it via a `for-loop`.

Comment: Great answer plus-one (-:

Comment: So. Much. Faster. than what I was thinking! (using `df[col].unique()`)